# Need to issue a confirmation dialog when "Delete" key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Okay so I have a DataGridView which is bound with my Data.

I have coded it to be in "edit" mode or "non-edit" mode with some buttons and

```
DGVSomeGrid.ReadOnly = true; //Or false when applicable.
```

The user is also allowed to delete rows, but I have to write this to my DataBase. There are foreign keys affected and thus I would like to invoke a warning | confirmation dialog with:

```
DialogResult = MessageBox.Show();
if (DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{} 
else if (DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{}
```

This I am fine with aswell.

My problem is I'm not really catching the right event (I think), and I'm not really sure how to cancel the delete procedure. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have experimented with:

```
keydown
```

and

```
keypress
```

events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont have much experience with Winforms but I think the [DataGridView.UserDeletingRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow(v=vs.100).aspx) Event is just what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect. LoL I was already handling this event to alter my DB, was just too silly to look at it. Thanks bud